# Laravel Carbon diff two times results wrong answer

Tags: laravel

This is the code running in tinker:

```
$a = Carbon\Carbon::parse("16:00")
$b = Carbon\Carbon::parse("23:00")
$b->diff($a)
```

the result is

```
 DateInterval {#4784
     interval: - 08:00:00.0,
   }
```

The difference is 7 hours not 8 hours!

This is scrrenshot

[image]

Comment: That's weird; I get `07:00:00.0`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNfmr.png

Comment: My machine also outputs 7.

Comment: What do each of the dates output? Time is always fun... is there a timezone set somewhere that may affect things? My dates are in UTC.

Comment: I took the liberty of checking your profile and plugged in your timezone of `Asia/Tehran`. With that set I **do** get 8.

Comment: @TimLewis I added screenshot

Comment: @BrianThompson I added screenshot

Comment: Based on [this site](https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/timezone/asia--tehran) with info on the timezone. It looks like you're about to change from daylight savings time today. This means you get an extra hour.

Comment: You can see this in your screenshot when it changes from +4:30 to only +3:30.

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks a lot

Comment: @BrianThompson what is solution?

Comment: There isn't really a "solution". It's expected. The general recommendation would be to use and store dates in UTC, and only convert them to locale specific timezones when displaying them. But I don't know your app or your requirements, so I don't know if that's feasible.